# Car Insurance Amount not debited

Tags: india, car-insurance

My Car insurance expired on 15th Feb 2014. I issued the check to broker on same day that is on 15th Feb, he gave me the receipt of check, but the amount of check has not been debited from my account. Will my insurance be continued  or discontinued. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Happening in india

Comment: What did the insurance company say when you phoned them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5 Days is too short a time. Typically it takes couple of weeks to process the renewal.
Chase your broker and find out what exactly happend. If its a large broker, there should'nt be issue.

If this was for more period of time then;
This would depend on who is at fault. If the broker did not deposit/give the check to the Insurance company and he is not a preffered borker, the Insurance company may reject and you are already out of cover.

If the broker did deposit the check and the Insurance company forgot to encash, then the Insurance company would have sent you a revised policy. If you have not received then you may not have cover.